# Fade scrolled text into image with CSS - almost here

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fade text when it is scrolled toward the top of the page. There are a lot of solutions, but I cannot find one that works when a background image is present. I did find a pen that used `mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1) 100px);` which I tried to modify to achieve my desired effect.

I am almost there in this pen: http://codepen.io/jdesilvio/pen/YwKpPp

I just can't get the fade to be `fixed` at the top of the page instead of scrolling with the text.

Here is the `CSS` I have so far:

```
.slab__content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 2rem;

    // Fade out with mask
   -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1) 300px);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1) 100px);
  }

.slab__content:after {
  position: fixed;
  content: "";
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  }
```

Comment: is this something that needs to be solved without javascript?

Comment: A solution with javascript would be fine!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think CSS has been developed so far that it can do this - [yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-mask-attachment)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a scroll event handler to window like so (assuming you have access to jquery):

```
$(window).on("scroll", function(e) {
  var text = $(".slab__content");
  text.css('mask-image', '-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) ' + ($('body').scrollTop()-200) + 'px , rgba(0,0,0,1)' +($('body').scrollTop()+300)+'px)');
})
```

Here we are changing the definition of style property mask-image based on the body's scroll position.

You can see this in action here (forked from your example): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMwoxQ